# Autoloading constants in PHP?

Tags: php, constants, autoload

I was hoping that if I were to define constants in a separate namespace, like:

```
namespace config\database\mysql;

const HOST = 'localhost';
const USER = 'testusr';
const PASSWORD = 'testpwd';
const NAME = 'testdb';
```

That I would be able to use `__autoload` to automatically include them:

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    echo "Autoload: {$className}\n";
    $class_file = str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . ".php";
    if(file_exists($class_file)) {
        include $class_file;
    }
}

echo config\database\mysql\HOST;
```

This, however, does not work. The `__autoload` is not called for the constant as it is with classes, leaving me with a `Undefined constant` error.

Some way that I can simulate the class `__autoload` for constants?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (worked on my server):

```
<?php
namespace config\database\mysql;

class Mysql
{
    const HOST = 'localhost';
    const USER = 'testusr';
    const PASSWORD = 'testpwd';
    const NAME = 'testdb';
}
?>

<?php
function __autoload($className)
{
    echo "Autoload: {$className}\n";
    $class_file = str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . ".php";
    if(file_exists($class_file)) {
        include $class_file;
    }
}

echo config\database\mysql\Mysql::HOST;
?>
```

Basically you need to create a class to act as a wrapper for the constants but by doing so it allows __autoload() to work as you intended.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I'm not to fond of having to wrap them up in dummy classes though, but it seems to work.

Answer (score -2):

Using an undefined constant will throw a PHP warning.

You can write a custom error handler to catch the warning and load in the appropriate constants file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the `Undefiend constant` error is a fatal error (`E_ERROR`), which a custom handler can't catch.

Comment: Hmm. Sure it used to be a notice, but I'm not using 5.3.

Comment: Wouldn't have worked anyway. Just gave it a try in 5.2 and, of course, the line triggering the error has already been processed so the constant definition isn't picked up until the next line. Hope you get a solution.